# Animate while working

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, animation, controls

My app has a custom user control (an ellipse with animation.) In my main window, I use both the usercontrol and a button

[image: Sample diagram]

I need to animate the control when the button is pressed:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            userControl11.BlueAnimate();
            dowork1();
            userControl11.RedAnimate();
            dowork2();
        }
    }
```

in my xml of the control i have the following definition:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Ellipse1Animation" x:Key="Ellipse1Animation">
        <DoubleAnimation
            x:Name="AnimacionEllipse"
            Storyboard.TargetName="_Ellipse"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1"
            AutoReverse ="True"
            RepeatBehavior="Forever"
            />
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The `userControl11.BlueAnimate();` has the following code (It is almost the same for the other method; the only change is the color cast.)

```
   Public Sub BlueAnimate()
        Dim AnimJob As Action = Function()
               Dispatcher.Invoke(DirectCast(
                          Function()
                          Dim sb As Storyboard = FindResource("Ellipse1Animation")
                          Dim Anim As DoubleAnimation = sb.Children(0)
                          _Ellipse.Fill = Brushes.Blue
                          Storyboard.SetTargetName(Anim, "_Ellipse")
                          sb.Begin()
               End Function, Action))
               End Function
        Task.Factory.StartNew(AnimJob )
    End Sub
```

When I cast the `userControl11.BlueAnimate`, it doesn't change. The visual interface stays frozen and doesn't work.  Can someone help?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: where is `sb.Begin()`?

Comment: In your `AnimJob` action, you seem to get the Storyboard from your xaml resources, then in the next line not sure what `sv` is(guess that's `sb`). `TargetName` for the Storyboard is already set in xaml so not sure why your setting that again in code-behind. Finally after doing all this you do not seem to actually "start" the animation. Try adding a `sb.Begin()` to the end of that action and you should see the animation work fine.

Comment: yes i forget to paste the sb.Begin() thats not the problem when i make a change in button1_Click taking out the dowork1 and dowork2 methods its animate perfect but when it have any heavy work after the animation start it keep frozen until the work ends

Comment: well that prolly means your dowork1() and dowork2() functions are blocking the UI thread. If the UI thread is blocked, it's not just the animation that would appear frozen but the entire UI all-together. Try dragging your app window once you click the button and see if the Window even moves. If it appears stuck, it's your dowork() functions indeed that need to be threaded.

Comment: thanks you I already make it work putting the  button1_Click on a BackGroundWorker